# Center Google map under header block in center on webpage

Tags: javascript, css, html, aptana

I am attempting to center my google map, but it does not want to move from being left aligned. Whenever I try to alter it, it removes my header.

My css code

```
#mapCanvas {
    width: 960px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

header {
    width: 960px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #339966;
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic; 
}

h1{ 
    color: white;
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px
}
p {
    color: white;
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic; 
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

My code in my html

```
<body>
    <header> 
        <h1>
            Find a user's location using HTML5 Geolocation
        </h1> 
        <p> If Geolocation sercive is failed, the University of Maryland Campus will be displayed on a map</p>
        </header>

    <div id="mapCanvas">

    </div>
</body>
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WZiy.jpg [My current results][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the rule for `#mapCanvas` for the left/right auto-margin centering to work.

Comment: how does the Google map get into that DIV?  Is there more code? (there has to be...)

Comment: through an API key and given lat &lng

Comment: well, seems like that also has its own CSS - check it in the browser tools / inspector

Comment: your right. seems i defined it early on in my html sheet.